# IPython Cluster using SSH

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

Having trouble starting cluster on remote machines. When starting cluster “manually” and copy json config files everything works. I can connect with notebook and everything works as expected.

But I would like to be able to start cluster over SSH.

- Host2 (2 engines)
- Host1  (Controller + 2 engines)
- Laptop - notebook

**Laptop**

```
ipython profile create --parallel --profile=ssh
```

**ipcluster_config.py**

```
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SSHEngineSetLauncher'
c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'SSHControllerLauncher'


c.SSHControllerLauncher.hostname = 'host1'
c.SSHControllerLauncher.user = 'root'
c.SSHControllerLauncher.controller_args = ['--reuse', '--ip=*', '--profile-dir=/root/.ipython/profile_ssh']
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {"host1":2, "host2":2}
```

Starting notebook

```
jupyter notebook --debug
```

When I start notebook cluster from ipython clusters tab. Engines connect to controller, files get copied etc. But when I try to connect with notebook

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
c = ipp.Client(profile='ssh',debug=True)
c.ids
c[:].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello, World")

“TimeoutError: Hub connection request timed out”
```

From console log I can see that engines are running and connected successfully.